# TabBarView inside a Positioned error Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm getting the error below when I try to run the code. I need the Containers inside the TabBarView to have their sizes set to (200 and 150), but I can't make it happen. My code only stops breaking when I use Positioned.fill or wrap the TabBarView in an Expanded, forcing the maximum height. However, I need the children of the TabBarView to have their minimum size, I've tried wrapping the TabBarView in a column and passing MainAxisSize.min, but I haven't had success either. Does anyone know what I can do to make the children's sizes have their minimum height? Note: I need to use two Positioned in this case.

> FlutterError (Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
> Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.)

```dart
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned( // <--  Not using Positioned.fill
              top: 43,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: TabBarView( // <-- And not using Expanded there, the children of TabBarView is not expanded, need min size
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  Container(height: 200,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: 
               BorderRadius.circular(15.0),                           
            color:Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                              ),),
                  Container(height: 150,color: Colors.green),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                  Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

I am not sure why `Stack` is required here. If it's mandatory, let me know. The below code and inline comment will help you understand using `TabBarView` in a better way.

**Tip 1:** You need either `Expanded` or `Flexible` to wrap your `TabBarView` to make it work as `TabBarView` has unbounded height

**Tip 2:** Wrap your `TabBarView` containers with Column and mention to keep the size as min.

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: const [
                Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
              ],
            ),
            Flexible(
              //Use Flexible instead of Expanded to shrink the height based on the children heights

              child: TabBarView(
                // <-- And not using Expanded there, the children of TabBarView is not expanded, need min size
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize
                        .min, //Wrap your view container with Column and mention to keep the size as min
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                          ),
                        ),
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          ),
                        ),
                        height: 150,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Stack and positioned are mandatory because I need to do something in the layout. I want to overlay the TabBar on top of the tabBarView.

Comment: @LucasBarretoLuz You could use Stack with the above logic as well. Let me it doesn't.

Comment: I tried using Stack, but I could only place the TabBar on top of the TabBarView using Positioned. I need the TabBar to be positioned just about 10px on top. Could you teach me how to do that?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot/had-drawn image of your expected result?

Comment: I have added the image of what I want to do. I'm trying to achieve the effect of this rounded border as shown in the image. However, I can only display it on the opposite side of the selected one. And I achieved this effect by stacking the tabBar in the TabBarView.

Comment: @LucasBarretoLuz
I have modified my code. Have a look. The inner page have the required rounded cosmetics. To optimise this you could create a template widget with the rounded effect and wrap each of your PageView widget with the template. Hope this helps